# Add watermark below image but within print area in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, printing, watermark

I am trying to insert a text watermark underneath a TIFF image in my windows form and would definitely appreciate anyone's help.  I have a print button that retrieves the image, scales it down, then based on my margins, places the image accordingly to print.  I'd like to add an additional piece where just before the image prints, I add in a text watermark (in this case a date stamp) that is just below the image.

I've tried adjusting the margin but that just increases (or decreases depending on the number setting) the image scale but does not add the additional room I want to add the watermark.  Below is code of what I have so far:

```
    protected void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Image == null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        //ADD TIME STAMP WATERMARK
        string watermark = "DATE ISSUED:  " + String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", System.DateTime.Now.Date); 
        System.Drawing.Graphics gpr = Graphics.FromImage(Image);
        System.Drawing.Brush brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 55, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(watermark, font);

        float x = 0;
        float y = Image.Height-size.Height;
        RectangleF printArea = new RectangleF(x, y, size.Width, size.Height);           
        gpr.DrawString(watermark, font, brush, printArea); 

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.Image, e.MarginBounds);

    }
```

The value of e.MarginBounds I have set in my App.config and include the following values:  Left=70, Right=90, Top=190; Bottom=475.  All the printouts are going to be printed portrait style on Letter 8 1/2 by 11 size paper.

I am able to display the watermark anywhere on top of the image, but I am hoping to place it underneath.  When I adjust the y coordinate, and it so happens to be below the image, when I print, I assume that it is outside the print area and therefore, the watermark does not get printed on the page (it only shows the image).

I appreciate anyone's help in this as I have been racking my brain on this and have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you printing your text beneath the image.  I think you want to start printing at y=Image.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top, and x=e.MarginBounds.Left

That will print a your label left justified below the image in the margin.

Update:  This works:

```
y=-size.Height + e.MarginBounds.Bottom; 
x = e.MarginBounds.Left; 
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, e.MarginBounds); 

// note the change.  Using e.graphics instead of gpr below
e.Graphics.DrawString(watermark, font, brush, printArea);
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to print the text beneath the image.  I will try your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I meant actually underneath (behind).  Unless your image was transparent it wouldn't let the text show through.  Try adding your text after the image is printed

Comment: The image(s) are not transparent.  I tried your suggestion and however, that did not work (the watermark is no where to be found on the print out).  I don't believe I have tried adding the text after the image is printed. Worth a try...

Comment: I also tried placing the text after the image print however, the text is no where to be found (for test purposes, used the coordinates of x=0 and y=0) on the printed page.  I'm still looking for a way to do this...

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've tried the above suggestions with no luck in trying to get this to work and display the watermark underneath the .TIFF image.

Comment: You're not using the right graphics object to print the text.  See update above.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks a bunch, and it was something I hadn't thought of trying!  Wow...Thanks for all your help.